# VHDL 4-Bit Multiplier: use_dsp48 and Gated clock

Tags: vhdl

the task is to make a 4-Bit Multiplier that uses FSM. the steps would be 1) multiply 2) shift 3) add.

> ```
>   1011   (this is 11 in binary)
>  x 1110   (this is 14 in binary)
>  ======
>    0000   (this is 1011 x 0)
>   1011    (this is 1011 x 1, shifted 1 position to the left)
>  1011     (this is 1011 x 1, shifted 2 positions to the left)
> 1011      (this is 1011 x 1, shifted three positions to the left)
> ======
> ```
>
> 10011010   (this is 154 in binary)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_multiplier

here are my codes:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity test is
    Port ( CLK : in  STD_LOGIC;
       RESET : in  STD_LOGIC;
       Input : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
       Confirm : in  STD_LOGIC;
       Output : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0));
end test;

architecture Behavioral of test is

type state is (R,S0,S1,S2,S3,S4);
signal pstate, nstate: state;
signal A_sig, B_sig: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);

begin
process(pstate,Confirm,Input)
variable temp_var: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
variable tempMult_var,tempProd_var: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
begin
    case pstate is
        when R =>
            nstate <= S0;
            tempMult_var := (others => '0');
            tempProd_var := (others => '0');

            A_sig <= (others => '0');
            B_sig <= (others => '0');

            Output <= (others => '0');
        when S0 =>
            nstate <= S0;

            if (Confirm = '1') then
                A_sig <= Input;
                nstate <= S1;
            end if;
        when S1 =>
            nstate <= S1;

            if (Confirm = '0') then
                nstate <= S2;
            end if;
        when S2 =>
            nstate <= S2;

            if (Confirm = '1') then
                B_sig <= Input;
                nstate <= S3;
            end if;
        when S3 =>
            nstate <= S3;

            if (Confirm = '0') then
                nstate <= S4;
            end if;
        when S4 =>
            nstate <= S0;

            for x in 0 to 3 loop
                temp_var := (A_sig AND (B_sig(x)&B_sig(x)&B_sig(x)&B_sig(x) ) );
                tempMult_var := "0000" & temp_var;
                if (x=0) then tempMult_var := tempMult_var;
                    elsif (x=1) then tempMult_var := tempMult_var(6 downto 0)&"0";
                    elsif (x=2) then tempMult_var := tempMult_var(5 downto 0)&"00";
                    elsif (x=3) then tempMult_var := tempMult_var(4 downto 0)&"000";        
                end if;
                tempProd_var := tempProd_var + tempMult_var;
            end loop;

            Output <= tempProd_var;
            tempProd_var := (others => '0');
    end case;
end process;

process(CLK,RESET)
begin
    if RESET = '1' then
        pstate <= R;
    elsif rising_edge(CLK) then
        pstate <= nstate;
    end if;
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

here are the warnings

```
after "Synthesize - XST"
WARNING:Xst - Property "use_dsp48" is not applicable for this technology.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 4-bit latch for signal <B_sig>.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 8-bit latch for signal <Output>.
WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 4-bit latch for signal <A_sig>.

after "Implement Design"
WARNING:Route:447 - CLK Net:A_sig_not0001 may have excessive skew because 
WARNING:Route:447 - CLK Net:B_sig_not0001 may have excessive skew because 

after "Generate Programming File"
WARNING:PhysDesignRules:372 - Gated clock. Clock net A_sig_not0001 is sourced by
WARNING:PhysDesignRules:372 - Gated clock. Clock net B_sig_not0001 is sourced by
WARNING:PhysDesignRules:372 - Gated clock. Clock net Output_or0000 is sourced by
```

the simulations are correct but the actual board doesn't have the correct output. what might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My humble advice:

> Combine your two processes into a single clocked process.

That way you avoid a whole category of asynchronous logic mistakes that are easy for a beginner to make to painful to track down.

Answer (score 0):

Also, whenever you see warnings about latches or gated clocks, revisit your code - both are clear indicators that something is most probably wrong.

Latches typically come from combinatorial processes where signals are only assigned in some cases. For instance `A_sig` is not assigned in S0, if `confirm = 0`, and will thus cause a latch to be inferred. In this case, just make sure that `A_sig` is always set to something, no matter the combination of the control signal values.

In this case the gated clocks probably come from your rather complex combinatorial process, but mostly it's from signals generated by logic for clocking synchronous processes. This can lead to all kind of problems (high FPGA clock line usage and timing/routing issues), especially if your not aware that you're creating additional clocking domains. This can mostly be avoided by running the process in question on the main (be it global or local) system clock and using a clock enable to scale it down if necessary.